# How to configure WebSphere portal to be crawled by Scrapy and ingested to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, scrapy

I want to crawl Websphere Portal8 using Scrapy, and ingest into elasticsearch.

Do I need to configure anything special in WP to be scroll/index friendly? e.g avoiding javascript based pages generation.

At present the crawling is getting only handful of pages, not 50k urls as expected.

Comment: Scrapy can handle JavaScript (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html). If your crawling is not working, then the issue is probably the spider code. You might want to rephrase your question or write a new question focused on how to fix your spider, instead of how to fix WP.

Comment: WebSphere Portal ships with a configurable Sitemap Portlet which might be useful to expose page URLs to crawlers.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYJ99_8.5.0/admin-system/srtcfgsitemap1.html